# Are getter/setters really useful?

Tags: javascript

I've read a lot about javascript  `getters/setters` and I am trying to find a good reason for using them instead of just using two methods in their place! Could someone give me a **small and intuitive** example through which their power will emerge and make me understand the usefulness of them?

No matter how much I searched I did not find such an example...

Comment: This looks interesting too: https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask

Comment: @Praveen KKumar, I believe the intent was to ask benefits of getters/setters for JS specifically.

Comment: @Rajesh That's a general topic, and I read it through, and found there's nothing specific we can say for JavaScript. All those things given there also suits it. Do you agree?

Comment: I completely agree to it, But just thought user is looking for some real life examples in JS world for it like `watchers`. Initially even I had this question but then came across frameworks like AngularJS and Knockout and saw this concept in action.

Comment: @ILIAS, Kindly refer `$.watch` in *Angular JS* or `subscribe` method of *Knockout JS* for real life use of getters and setters